# Apache + Varnish = High CPU Usage

Tags: apache-2.4, varnish, central-processing-unit

I've installed Varnish to our server a few hours ago and edited both default.vcl and varnish files as follows. The website is much faster now. However when i use the TOP commmand i noticed a seriously high CPU/RAM usage on Apache. What do you think could make such a problem in the settings?

Centos 6, 
Directadmin, 
Varnish 4, 
Wordpress + Total W3 Cache.

Default.vcl:

```
/* SET THE HOST AND PORT OF WORDPRESS
 * *********************************************************/
vcl 4.0;
import std;

backend default {
  .host = "MY SERVER IP";
  .port = "8080";
  .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
  .connect_timeout = 300s;
}

# SET THE ALLOWED IP OF PURGE REQUESTS
# ##########################################################
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}

#THE RECV FUNCTION
# ##########################################################
sub vcl_recv {

# set realIP by trimming CloudFlare IP which will be used for various checks
set req.http.X-Actual-IP = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "[, ].*$", ""); 

        # FORWARD THE IP OF THE REQUEST
  if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
      req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
  }

 # Purge request check sections for hash_always_miss, purge and ban
 # BLOCK IF NOT IP is not in purge acl
 # ##########################################################

  # Enable smart refreshing using hash_always_miss
if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
    if (client.ip ~ purge || !std.ip(req.http.X-Actual-IP, "1.2.3.4") ~ purge) {
         set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
}

if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge || !std.ip(req.http.X-Actual-IP, "1.2.3.4") ~ purge) {
        return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
        }
    return (purge);
  }

if (req.method == "BAN") {
        # Same ACL check as above:
        if (!client.ip ~ purge || !std.ip(req.http.X-Actual-IP, "1.2.3.4") ~ purge) {
                        return(synth(403, "Not allowed."));
        }
        ban("req.http.host == " + req.http.host +
                  " && req.url == " + req.url);

        # Throw a synthetic page so the
        # request won't go to the backend.
        return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
}

# Unset cloudflare cookies
# Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
      # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
     set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

  # For Testing: If you want to test with Varnish passing (not caching) uncomment
  # return( pass );

  # FORWARD THE IP OF THE REQUEST
  if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
      req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
  }

# DO NOT CACHE RSS FEED
 if (req.url ~ "/feed(/)?") {
    return ( pass ); 
}

## Do not cache search results, comment these 3 lines if you do want to cache them

if (req.url ~ "/\?s\=") {
    return ( pass ); 
}

# CLEAN UP THE ENCODING HEADER.
  # SET TO GZIP, DEFLATE, OR REMOVE ENTIRELY.  WITH VARY ACCEPT-ENCODING
  # VARNISH WILL CREATE SEPARATE CACHES FOR EACH
  # DO NOT ACCEPT-ENCODING IMAGES, ZIPPED FILES, AUDIO, ETC.
  # ##########################################################
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
      # No point in compressing these
      unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
      # unknown algorithm
      unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
  }

  # PIPE ALL NON-STANDARD REQUESTS
  # ##########################################################
  if (req.method != "GET" &&
    req.method != "HEAD" &&
    req.method != "PUT" && 
    req.method != "POST" &&
    req.method != "TRACE" &&
    req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.method != "DELETE") {
      return (pipe);
  }

  # ONLY CACHE GET AND HEAD REQUESTS
  # ##########################################################
  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
  }

  # OPTIONAL: DO NOT CACHE LOGGED IN USERS (THIS OCCURS IN FETCH TOO, EITHER
  # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT BOTH
  # ##########################################################
  if ( req.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in" ) {
    return( pass );
  }

  # IF THE REQUEST IS NOT FOR A PREVIEW, WP-ADMIN OR WP-LOGIN
  # THEN UNSET THE COOKIES
  # ##########################################################
  if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)") 
    && !(req.url ~ "&preview=true" ) 
  ){
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

  # IF BASIC AUTH IS ON THEN DO NOT CACHE
  # ##########################################################
  if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    return (pass);
  }

  # IF YOU GET HERE THEN THIS REQUEST SHOULD BE CACHED
  # ##########################################################
  return (hash);
  # This is for phpmyadmin
if (req.http.Host == "ki1.org") {
return (pass);
}

if (req.http.Host == "mysql.ki1.org") {
return (pass);
}

}

# HIT FUNCTION
# ##########################################################
sub vcl_hit {
  # IF THIS IS A PURGE REQUEST THEN DO THE PURGE
  # ##########################################################
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    #
    # This is now handled in vcl_recv.
    #
    # purge;
    return (synth(200, "Purged."));
  }
  return (deliver);
}

# MISS FUNCTION
# ##########################################################
sub vcl_miss {
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    #
    # This is now handled in vcl_recv.
    #
    # purge;
    return (synth(200, "Purged."));
  }
  return (fetch);
}

# FETCH FUNCTION
# ##########################################################
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # I SET THE VARY TO ACCEPT-ENCODING, THIS OVERRIDES W3TC 
  # TENDANCY TO SET VARY USER-AGENT.  YOU MAY OR MAY NOT WANT
  # TO DO THIS
  # ##########################################################
  set beresp.http.Vary = "Accept-Encoding";

  # IF NOT WP-ADMIN THEN UNSET COOKIES AND SET THE AMOUNT OF 
  # TIME THIS PAGE WILL STAY CACHED (TTL)
  # ##########################################################
  if (!(bereq.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)") && !bereq.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in" ) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 52w;
#    set beresp.grace =1w;
  }

  if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
    beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
    beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
      set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
      # set beresp.ttl = 120s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
      return (deliver);
  }

  return (deliver);
}

# DELIVER FUNCTION
# ##########################################################
sub vcl_deliver {
  # IF THIS PAGE IS ALREADY CACHED THEN RETURN A 'HIT' TEXT 
  # IN THE HEADER (GREAT FOR DEBUGGING)
  # ##########################################################
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  # IF THIS IS A MISS RETURN THAT IN THE HEADER
  # ##########################################################
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}
```

Varnish:

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variable $DAEMON_OPTS to be set from this
# shell script fragment.
#

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Locked shared memory (for ulimit -l)
# Default log size is 82MB + header
MEMLOCK=82000

# Maximum number of threads (for ulimit -u)
NPROCS="unlimited"

# Maximum size of corefile (for ulimit -c). Default in Fedora is 0
# DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT="unlimited"

# Set this to 1 to make init script reload try to switch vcl without restart.
# To make this work, you need to set the following variables
# explicit: VARNISH_VCL_CONF, VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS,
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT, VARNISH_SECRET_FILE, or in short,
# use Alternative 3, Advanced configuration, below
RELOAD_VCL=1

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a fixed-size cache file.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#             -T localhost:6082 \
#             -b localhost:8080 \
#             -u varnish -g varnish \
#             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a
# fixed-size cache file.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80
             -T localhost:6082 
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl 
             -S /etc/varnish/secret 
             -s malloc,2G"


## Alternative 3, Advanced configuration
#
# See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# # Default address and port to bind to
# # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify
# # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
#
# # Telnet admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
#
# # Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
#
# # The minimum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=1
#
# # The Maximum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
#
# # Idle timeout for worker threads
VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120
#
# # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,
# # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.
VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G
#
# # Backend storage specification
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
#
# # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
VARNISH_TTL=120
#
# # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make
# # sure you update this section, too.
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
             -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
             -p thread_pool_min=${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS} \
             -p thread_pool_max=${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS} \
             -p thread_pool_timeout=${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
             -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
#


## Alternative 4, Do It Yourself. See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

**VARNISHSTAT**

[image: VARNISHSTAT]

**Top**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not really high RAM usage for apache, it's pretty standard for a larger PHP application.

You might find that you get better RAM performance if you offload PHP to php-fpm or fastcgi. There are quite guides available to help you configure it, a quick google for apache + centos + fastcgi php resulted in:
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-centos-6.2

Note: some of these changes can break your system, and will take down webserving for a little while. Follow guides with care!